# Can I bring soil samples from Cuba / US to Switzerland?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, switzerland

A friend of mine asked me to collect some soil samples abroad and bring them to Switzerland, she collects them as a hobby.
Will I run into problems when bringing these through customs (both out of the country and into Switzerland)?

I am mainly interested in Cuba and the United States, however I am also interested in other countries regulations.

Additional info: I am talking about a handful of soil each for a couple of different locations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To bring soil into the USA you need an APHIS permit.  While perhaps you could apply for a permit, there are attached rules requiring treatment of that soil to assure no pests enter the USA.  So from a practical point of view, the answer would be no.

https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/955/kw/soil%20samples/session/L3RpbWUvMTQ2MjMzNjk5Ny9zaWQvKm5qVy1DUG0%3D/suggested/1